Uncomplete argument in Nishioka book
In Nishioka book "Mahler functions and transcendence" in the proof of Theorem 4.2.1, Nishioka asserts the following: For a matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{1\le i\le m}$ with coefficients in $K[z]$ ($K$ a number field). If $R(z,X_0,\cdots,X_m)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of $K[z,X_0,\cdots,X_m]$ of degree $p$ in the variables $\underline X=(X_0,\cdots,X_m)$ then the polynomial $R(z^q,X_0,A_1(\underline x,z),\cdots,A_m(\underline x,z))$ ($\underline x=(X_1,\cdots,X_m)$) is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $p$ in $\underline X$ where for all integer $i$ in $[1,m]$ $A_i$ is the linear form in $\underline x$ given by $A_i(\underline x,z)=a_{i,1}(z)x_1+\cdots+a_{i,m}(z)x_m$.
In Nishioka Theorem, there is no condition on $A$. But, that's trivially false (consider A the matrix null). Can one give natural conditions on $A$ to save the proof?
Thanks in advance for any answer.

From a quick skim, $A$ here is not a totally random matrix, but a coefficient in a certain functional equation.  For example, if $A$ equals $0$, then, in Nishioka's notation, $f_1(z), \dotsc, f_m(z)$ belong to $K(z)$.  I haven't taken the time to check the consequences of this; have you done so and seen what happens to the rest of the proof in this setting?
